# How to create a corpus with a set of text files - python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, corpus

I have a set of document `ID`s (keys.csv) that I am using to get a set of text documents from a document source. I would like to collect all these text documents into a corpus for further analysis (like cosine similarity).

I am using the below code to append each text document into the corpus, but I'm not sure if this is going to work. Is there a better way to create a corpus with these text documents?

```
keys = pandas.read_csv(keys.csv)
for i in keys:
    ID = i
    doc = function_to_get_document(ID)
    corpus = corpus.append(doc)
```

Comment: `corpus` is a list right?

Comment: The best answer would be to test it and see if it serves your purposes. More, your `ID` variable is useless.

Comment: Maybe something like `corpus = [function_to_get_document(ID) for ID in pandas.read_csv(keys.csv)]` ?

Comment: No. You do not assign the result of `corpus.append` back to `corpus`, since `corpus.append` **always** returns `None`. You just need `corpus.append(doc)`

Comment: What do you actually mean by `corpus` here?

Comment: @AlexFung, yes, corpus is a list here.

Comment: @VivekKumar, I mean a list of all the text documents together.

Comment: @Minu You said that you wanted "corpus for further analysis (like cosine similarity)". Thats why I asked. For just a list of all documents, the answer given by @jezrael is correct. Just replace the `function_to_get_document()` with your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `csv` has column `IDcol` with unique `ID` use `list comprehension`, output is `list`:

```
corpus = [function_to_get_document(ID) for ID in pd.read_csv('keys.csv')['IDcol']]
```

Sample:

```
print (pd.read_csv('keys.csv'))
   IDcol
0      1
1      2
2      3

def function_to_get_document(x):
    return x + 1

corpus = [function_to_get_document(ID) for ID in pd.read_csv('keys.csv')['IDcol']]
print (corpus)
[2, 3, 4]
```